# Copying directory fails sometimes with "access denied"

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting

I am executing a PowerShell script and this line:

```psh
Copy-Item -Path "$A_DIRECTORY" -Destination "$ANOTHER_DIRECTORY" -Recurse -Force
```

intermittently fails with the following error:

```
Copy-Item : Access is denied
At C:\mydir\build.ps1:224 char:5
+     Copy-Item -Path "$A_DIRECTORY" -Destination "$ANOTHER_DIRECTORY" ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Copy-Item], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

Now, the error message is clear, but it does not make sense because the target directory does not exist. I have write permissions and also tried to run as administrator with same result.

Why would this statement fail sometimes but not always? Perhaps it is also worth noting that `$ANOTHER_DIRECTORY` is deleted in the command preceding this one. The delete operation never fails.

Comment: Are you running any sort of AV on this computer? The reason I'm asking, is that this sort of error could be caused by interference from another process, holding onto the directory while it's being deleted. I can reproduce the issue: **1.** run this code in infinite loop `While ($true) {remove-item "c:\temp1\etc" -recurse -force; copy-item -path "c:\temp\etc" -destination "c:\temp1\etc" -recurse -force}`  This runs just fine... **2.** Whilst running, use explorer to browse to folder "c:\temp1\etc" You will get the same error.

Comment: It may be that your file system is still in the process of deleting the previous folder. I would be tempted to add a `While(Test-Path $ANOTHER_DIRECTORY){Start-Sleep 5}` just before your copy command, or after your delete command.